# How to Skip Rows in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, indexing, cell-formatting

I've only seen information on deleting rows or removing rows. I am trying to skip a row and display information. I haven't been able to find any information on that.

For example I have an array of products = ['Broom', 'Mop', 'Chair', 'Pan']. I want to display it in my tableview where it displays as:

Broom

skip a cell

Mop

skip a cell

Chair

skip a cell

Pan

skip a cell

I have the count times two to have enough rows and I created a second row to help with the skip process.

Here's what I have so far. However, the issue is it skips the actual item not the next cell. So it instead does:

Broom

skip a cell

Chair

skip a cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let index = indexPath.row

    if (index % 2) == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productsblock", for: indexPath ) as! DetailTBCell

        return cell
    } else {
        let spacecell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "spacingcell", for: indexPath ) as! DetailSpaceTBCell
        
        return spacecell
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have “skip a cell” then your data model is wrong. It needs to contain an entry for _every_ row of the table. You shouldn’t have to pull any trickery in the data source methods. The data model should supply the data smoothly. Fix that friction.

Answer (score 0):

As @matt said, you should just have a data source that contains placeholders. Try something like this:

```
let items = ["Broom", "Mop", "Chair", "Pan"]
var expandedItems = [String]()

func expandArray() { /// call this to add placeholders
    var temporaryExpandedItems = [String]()
    for item in items {
        temporaryExpandedItems.append(item)
        temporaryExpandedItems.append("") /// add a placeholder
    }
    expandedItems = temporaryExpandedItems
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return expandedItems.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let index = indexPath.row
    let currentItem = expandedItems[index]

    if currentItem != "" {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productsblock", for: indexPath ) as! DetailTBCell

        return cell
    } else { /// skip this placeholder
        let spacecell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "spacingcell", for: indexPath ) as! DetailSpaceTBCell
        
        return spacecell
    }
}
```